# Tandem Neural Network, input shape error

Tags: neural-network

I am training a tandem setup, which includes a reverse network and a forward network.
The flow of data is:
$Y \to$ reverse network $\to X \to$ forward network $\to Y'$

The loss function will be the sum of all $(Y-Y')^2$, see `custom_loss`.

The forward network is pre-trained, and it is pretty good at predicting $Y'$ from $X$. The training was done elsewhere, and the good forward network is just loaded into the code.

Now that I am training the reverse network using the tandem structure, there is some issues regarding how to connect the layers to run the training properly.

---

The code I have is the following:

```py
    forward_loaded = tf.keras.models.load_model("M70_H5_saved.h5")
    forward_loaded.trainable = False

def build_model_reverse1():
    # Reverse model --------------------------------------------
    input_layer = Input(shape=(len(train_reverse.columns),)) 

    #layer 1 ----------------------------------------------
    first_dense = Dense(units='16', activation='relu')(input_layer)

    #layer 2 ----------------------------------------------
    second_dense = Dense(units='16', activation='relu')(first_dense)

    Dx_output = Dense(units='1', name='Dx_output')(second_dense)
    Dy_output = Dense(units='1', name='Dy_output')(second_dense)

    #forward model --------------------------------------------------
    #responce_out = forward_try.predict([Dx_output, Dy_output])

    # Define the model with the input layer and a list of output layers
    model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[Dx_output, Dy_output])

    return model
reverse_01= build_model_reverse1()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
reverse_01.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss={'Dx_output': 'mse', 'Dy_output': 'mse'})

# Train the model for 5 epochs
history_reverse_01 = reverse_01.fit(norm_train_X_rev, train_Y_reverse, epochs=5, validation_data=(norm_test_X_rev, test_Y_reverse))
```

---

### The error I'm getting is:
Epoch 1/100

```
Epoch 1/5
52/63 [=======================>......] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1101795.6250 - Dx_output_loss: 542089.3125 - Dy_output_loss: 559706.6250
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-ec3351595224> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Train the model for 100 epochs
----> 2 history_reverse_01 = reverse_01.fit(norm_train_X_rev, train_Y_reverse, epochs=5, validation_data=(norm_test_X_rev, test_Y_reverse))
      3 
      4 #visualy compare with forward model training call
      5 #history_70 = forward_70.fit(norm_train_X_forw, train_Y_forward, epochs=100, batch_size=10, validation_data=(norm_test_X_forw, test_Y_forward))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__test_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1852, in test_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1836, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1824, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.test_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1788, in test_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=False)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 4), found shape=(None, 2)
```

---

Note that:
norm_train_X_rev.shape = (2000,4)

norm_test_X_rev.shape = (500,4)

len(train_reverse.columns) = 4

and the train_Y_reverse and test_Y_reverse are both tuples

Iam not sure why there is a shape error when it expect a shape of shape=(None, 4), but I am inputting norm_train_X_rev, which should have the right shape (?)
Any comments, solutions and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Actually your issue is about the *shape* of `X_train`. The error says "Layer "model_1" expects 1 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors [...]". You set the input shape to `(4)` but the model received for tensors each of shape `(10,)`. Maybe you need to reshape or concatenate `X_train` first to have a shape of `(N, 4)` where `N` is the number of samples.

Comment: Thank you! I have made some changes to fix the input shapes. So far there seems to be another similar error.